Numerical integration with modified Bessel function of second kind
I am working with the so-called screened Poisson PDE, whose solutions in two-dimensions are given in terms of the modified Bessel function of the second kind, $K_0$, for Dirichlet boundary conditions vanishing at infinity. By considering a source term $S(x,y)$, apart from multiplicative constants the solution $u(x,y)$ of the PDE is
$$
u(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K_0(c\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2})S(x',y') \mathrm{d}x'\mathrm{d}y',
$$
where $c > 0$ is a real constant. This solution must be finite at the origin, where $K_0$ is known to diverge logarithmically. Therefore, the numerical integration of the above equation should be more stable if we change to polar coordinates $(x',y')\to(r',\theta')$, as this transformation produces $\mathrm{d}x'\mathrm{d}y'\to r\mathrm{d}r'\mathrm{d}\theta'$, and $r$ goes to zero faster than $K_0$ diverges at the origin. Indeed, the numerical results are much better by applying this transformation, but still some errors appear occasionally. So, my question is: is there a better transformation to make this numerical integration easier?
Currenlty, I am using MATLAB to perform such numerical calculations, but preliminar results with Mathematica seem to be unchanged. Explicitly, $S(x,y)\propto \exp(-ax^2)\exp(-by^2)$, where $a\neq b$ are real constants, so the source is well-behaved at the origin and the transformation to polar coordinates still yields a double integral.
